# Hello, issue with this command apt-get

Tags: apt

```
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (2: No such file or directory)
E: Unable to lock the list directory
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? What command did you try to execute?

Answer (score 0):

Well that's because ubuntu is already performing an update/upgrade task without you knowing it,ie. regularly check for updates. If you want access immediately run:
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock